# undefined method `expr' for nil:NilClass after upgrading to rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two following models

```
    class Machine < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :machine_part_changes
        has_one :current_identifier_part_change, -> {
        sql = <<-SQL
          INNER JOIN "machine_parts"
          ON "machine_parts"."id" = "machine_part_changes"."machine_part_id"
          AND "machine_parts"."is_machine_external_identifier" = 1
        SQL
        installed.joins(sql)
        },
        class_name: 'MachinePartChange'
    end

    class MachinePartChange < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :machine_part
      belongs_to :machine, touch: true
    end
```

in rails 4.2 I was able to do like

```
Machine.eager_load(:current_identifier_part_change).first
```

but now after I upgrade to rails 5.2 I am getting following error when I run tests.

```
    Failure/Error: machine = Machine.eager_load(:current_identifier_part_change).find(create_machine.id)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `expr' for nil:NilClass
```

I do not have much knowledge of sql :-( and code is written some other developer what can I do to pass this test.

Comment: What's the code on the line that is calling `expr`? Could simply be a typo

Comment: Possibly: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32671 (closed but never fixed)

Comment: @SexxLuthor yes I have referenced it in rails issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34456 which is still open